# convert a javascript function into a method

Tags: javascript, methods

I have a javascript procedural function working with objects belonging to class A:

```
function max(a, b) {
  if (a > b)
    return a;
  else
    return b;
}
a = max(a, b);
```

I want to convert it into a method; a try would be:

```
A.prototype.max = function(b) {
  if (this > b) {
    // do nothing
  } else {
    this = b;
  }
}
a.max(b);
```

but obviously it doesnt' work, because `this` can't be assigned.

How can I do?

Comment: The simple answer is that you can't.

Comment: Is your goal to make it so after calling `a.max(b);`, if `b` is larger, then printing `a` on the next line will result in the value stored in `b`?

Comment: There's nothing procedural about your function. It doesn't have side effects and instead returns a result like a proper function.

Comment: Please post the whole code of your "class `A`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the correct thing to do in this case would be to assign the value of `a` as a property of the class.  You could even pass it in on creation:

```
class A {
  constructor(val = null) {
    this.value = val;
   }

   this.max = function(b) {
     if (this.value > b){
       // do nothing
      } else {
        this.value = b;
      }
   }
}
```

Replace null with any default value you want, if you don't need to pass it in on creation, or just replace `val` in the constructor with the default value and take it out as an argument altogether:

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.value = aDefaultValueForAllInstances;
   }
...
```

Or, with an arrow function, the method would be:

```
   this.max = (b) => {
     if (this.value > b){
       // do nothing
      } else {
        this.value = b;
      }
   }
```

You could also simplify the if statement:

```
if (b < this.value){
  this.value = b;
}
```

A good sign that you can simplify an `if` statement is if you aren't doing something in part of it.

If your code is actually this simple then, realistically, you're probably better off just leaving it procedural as it is.